# Android - Adding my app's buttons to the lock screen?

Tags: android, button, lockscreen

This is my first Android app, and first java app in general so the more detailed the answers/examples the better.

I've got three buttons in my app.  I'd like these same three buttons to be accessible on the lock screen.  They're not media controls, but actual buttons that when pressed fire up or interact with a running thread.

Any suggestions?  Links to examples?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Google's documentation

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: AFAIK, lockscreen widgets were removed in Lollipop to this could no longer be valid.

Comment: You seem to be right, and the documentation is not updated. Still, for pre-lollipop devices the answer is correct.